# Mathematica says that a variable is not defined, yet it gives me a value

Tags: symbols, variable

this is probably a dumb question (Mathematica noob here) but I can't figure out what's going on.  I have a variable that I assign a value to and use, then later in the notebook I assign it a different value and reuse it for a similar calculation, and now I want to clear its value and just have it act as a variable.  However I get this:

[image: Strange Mathematica variable behavior]

As you can hopefully see in the image, I am unable to clear the variable w_i, however when I ask the value of the variable it tells me what I previously assigned to it (w_p and w_s are also symbols).  Also note that the coloration of the variable indicates that it is undefined, including when I explicitly define it above to the value listed here, and when I assigned it a test value in the image.  It should have turned from blue to black when I evaluated that cell.  Are there some fancy commands that I can use to figure out what is going on with w_i?

I realize that I could and probably should be using a Module[] block for namespace handling since I use the same variable name in multiple places, it just peeves me that Mathematica has so many little quirks like this.

Comment: Subscripted variables are not symbols unless you `Symbolize` them after loading the `Notation` package.  Look up the help on that package.  Generally subscripted variables are not a good idea in Mathematica.  While `Clear` does not work, you can remove an assignment with $\omega _i=.$